# regex all symbols/characters after first 15

Tags: regex

I have some text, for instance: `"some some 2text fo,r exam$ple"`. How can I take all characters including alpha, digits, slashes, dotes and everything after first 10 characters with regex?

input:

```
"some some 2text fo,r exam$ple"
```

output:

```
"2text fo,r exam$ple"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the regex pattern:

```
(?<=^.{10}).*$
```

### Demo

This would match all characters excluding the first ten.  If your regex flavor does not support lookbehinds, then use:

```
^.{10}(.*)$
```

Then, use the first capture group to get the text you want to match.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i can use terminal for this.

Comment: @joosilver Sorry...for some reason I thought you were using R.  Check the updated answer for two pure regex options.

Comment: ...or, with PCRE (PHP),  Onigmo (incl. Ruby) and possibly other regex engines, `^.{10}\K.*$`, where `\K` more-or-less means forget about the match so far.